# C++ request change of const data (through pointer) from non-const pointer owner

Tags: c++, json, pointers, reference, nlohmann-json

suppose i have a reference to a const nlohmann::json object, and the owner of the data has a non-const version of it.
i would like to request a change of the data from the owner. I would like to pass a pointer to the specific key i wish to change, and the new value it should be given, and let the owner decide if my request is valid. is this behavior possible?
example:

```
main()
{
   using namespace nlohmann;
   json j << someJsonFile; // it's structure and keys are known to all.
   
   const json& constJsonRef = j;

   // Could this function be implemented?
   RequestDataChange(j, constJsonRef[SomeKey], 6);

   // if request is found valid, then j[SomeKey] should be 6.
}
```

Comment: What does RequestDataChange look like?

Comment: some general validations about the new data, checking it's of the right type and such @kiner_shah

Comment: I meant the function signature.

Comment: it doesn't really matter to me, but it should a pointer to the const json value i wish to change, a pointer to the non const json object, and the new value.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please rephrase the question and elaborate so that it's clear to understand.

Comment: Yes, totally possible. Now go and implement it.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow some help with how to? I'm having a hard time figuring this out